# Load version of package for a given date in Pharo

Tags: pharo, monticello, metacello

I am looking for a way to, given a package name, load a version of that package that was the newest version at a given date.

For example:

```
HypotheticalClassLoader loadPackage: 'Athens-Core' onDate: ('12.03.2015' asDate).
```

Would load the first commit of 'Athens-Core' that is older than 12.03.2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following script. It should detect the first version before a given date.

```
goferReferences := Gofer new
   url: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/Pharo/Athens/main';
   package: 'Athens-Core'
   constraint: [ :goferReference |
      goferReference version info date < '12 June 2015' asDate];
   resolved.

goferReferences ifNotNil: [
   Gofer new
      url: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/Pharo/Athens/main';
      version: goferReferences first name;
      load ]
```